# How to read percentage?

Tags: readings, mathematics

How to read `１２．５％`? I've place it on Google Translate and heard じゅうに**てん**パーセント, is it correct?

> ６５歳を超えるアメリカ人は全人口の**１２．５％**を構成している。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ・ here is used as the "." would be used in English: to distinguish the round and the decimal part. So it is indeed read as 点{てん}.

So you would read the whole thing as [１２]{じゅうに}[・]｛てん｝[５]｛ご｝[％]｛パーセント｝.

Answer (score 4):

The correct pronunciation is :
じゅう に てん ご パーセント

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** correct. Its pronunciation is Jū ni-ten **go** pāsento. (じゅう に てん ご ぱーせんと)